# Refer to another webpage when pressing the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal:
Go to webpage test3 by pressing the button (id=hello)

Problem:
What part of the code when I pressing the button button am I missing in order to work in relation to react js code?

Info:
*I'm new in reactJS

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/redirect-to-default-route-reactjs-8qa9ah?file=index.js

---

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Test1 from "./Test1";
import Test2 from "./Test2";
import Test3 from "./Test3";
import Test11 from "./test11";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isUserAuthenticated: true
    };
  }

  sayHello(link) {
    alert(`hello, ${link}`);

    return <Redirect to="/test3" />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/test1">Test 1</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/test2">Test 2</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/test3">Test 3</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <button
              id="hello"
              value="test3"
              onClick={e => this.sayHello(e.target.value)}
            >
              Go to page test3
            </button>

            <hr />
            <Switch>
              <Route
                exact
                path="/"
                render={() => {
                  return this.state.isUserAuthenticated ? (
                    <Redirect to="/home" />
                  ) : (
                    <Redirect to="/test1" />
                  );
                }}
              />
              <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/test1/test11" component={Test11} />
              <Route exact path="/test1" component={Test1} />
              <Route exact path="/test2" component={Test2} />
              <Route exact path="/test3" component={Test3} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: [`Redirect`](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Redirect) is a component that must be rendered to have any effect. `onClick` does not return anything (even if you're assigned function does), so the `Redirect` has no effect. Use `history`  instead. or Restructure your class to cause `Redirect` to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use history object from props and you should push your location to desired path:

*NOTE: You probably will have to use withRouter() when exporting the App component.*

```
sayHello(link) {
    alert(`hello, ${link}`);
    this.props.history.push("/test3")
  }
```